# Find a string in a file C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I am trying to parse a file in C++. My file contents are as follows:

```
//Comments should be ignored

FileVersion,1;
Count,5;
C:\Test\Files\Test_1.txt 0,16777216,16777552,0,0,1,0,1,1,1;
```

FileVersion is the first line I need to read information. All the previous lines are just comments which begin with a '//'. How do I set my cursor to line containing FileVersion? Becuase I am using fscanf to read the information from the file.

```
if  (  1 != fscanf( f, "FileVersion,%d;\n", &lFileVersion ))
{
     //Successfully read the file version.
}
```

Comment: `fscanf` is a C function. If you wanted a C solution, why did you tag this as C++?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it is also valid C++. But streams do generally help with I/O

Comment: I included the C tag as well.

Comment: So, what's wrong with your posted solution? What are you trying to improve?

Comment: When I have comments, FileVersion is not read. It fscanf returns 0.

Comment: @clcto I indeed assumed that he was running C code in a C++ environment. It was just that it is ambiguous as to what kind of solution he wants (C vs C++). It's now even more ambiguous now that he updated the tags. But I guess he will accept either.

Comment: @0x499602D2: fscanf is a valid function in C++, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/. I am looking for a solution in C++, please read the question properly.

Comment: consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865335/when-why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-the-fscanf-function for arguments against fscanf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to write parsers (assuming "line-based") by reading a line at a time, and then using `sscanf` `strncmp` and `strcmp` (or C++'s `std::stringstream` and `std::string::substr`) to check for various content.

In your example, something like:

```
enum Sates
{
    Version = 1,
    Count   = 2,
    ...
} state = Version;

char buffer[MAXLEN];
while(fgets(buffer, MAXLEN, f) != NULL)
{
   if (0 == strncmp("//", buffer, 2))
   {
      // Comment. Skip this line.
      continue;
   }
   switch (state) 
   {
       case Version:
          if (0 == strncmp("FileVersion,", buffer, 12))
          {
             if (1 == sscanf(buffer, "FileVersion,%d;", &version))
             {
                  state = Count;
                  break;
             }
             Error("Expected file version number...");
          }
          break;
       ... 
   }
}
```

There are of course oodles of other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged C++, I will give you a C++ solution.

You can use a single call to `f.ignore()` to discard the first line of the stream:

```c++
f.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Technically this skips everything up and including the newline at the end of the first line, so the stream position will be just before the newline on the *second* line. Formatted I/O discards leading whitespace so this will be no issue.

The above requires the use of C++ file streams since this is C++, and the use of the formatted operators `operator>>()` and `operator<<()` to perform input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Not a particular C++ solution, but:

1. read a line with `fgets` (oh okay, if you want, you can substitute a C++ function for that);
2. if it starts with your 'comment' designator, skip to end of loop
3. if the line is empty (i.e., it contains only a hard return; or, possibly, check for zero or more whitespace characters and *then* an end-of-line), skip to end of loop
4. at end of loop: if you got something else, use `sscanf` on that string.